# Android Studio Gradle Project Sync Failed 0.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-gradle-plugin

I'm just trying to sync a project but it's telling me that I have to install the Android Support Repository but I already did that and is still giving me a error. I am new to Android Studio so I really still know know my way around please help me out.

Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+] on root project 'Wearable'.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and the Android Studio likely use ***two different copies of the SDK***.